# Selected item of Dropdownlist will generates checkboxlist dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am looking about project example where when I select one of many dropdownlists, then will generate a checkboxlist. (Of course we talking about one to many connection, one - dropdownlist, many - checkboxes). I have never use ajax and javascript so it will be great if somebody show me some similar project or article. I cant find any similar projects.

Comment: Hello... I should make an attempt 1st, then post your code to see how far you've got... then people will assist.

Comment: Seriously i dont know how to start ;d

Comment: Try this for JavaScript.. I learnt most my stuff from this https://www.w3schools.com/js/. There are loads of examples of Ajax posting on this site. What you're asking is very specific. I've not done a project with the functionality you have said. Stat off with a project with 1 view and a drop down and try to capture the change event of the dropdown go from there.